# How does the iPhone Google image search touch-event functionality work?

Tags: javascript, iphone, touch, mobile-safari, google-apps

When I do a Google image search on my iPhone within the Safari mobile browser, it gives me this beautiful interface for flipping through the images.  If I swipe left or right, it browses through the images.  If I touch and move up or down, I get what appears to be the native Safari scroll function.  Can anyone explain how Google does this?  I'm only beginning to learn the Safari API for touch events.  It seems like either you capture the touch event to attach handlers to swipe left or right or you let Safari handle the touch events natively, in which case you get the beautiful native Safari scrolling.  Can anyone explain how Google captures left/right swipe but not scrolling?

Comment: I'm referring to behavior within Mobile Safari, so I believe it must use the Safari API for touch events: ontouchstart, ontouchmove, etc.

Comment: I don't think that it is a safari api. It is simple html/css and java script

Comment: eh, well, it has to do with touch events.  JavaScript cannot detect these events on its own, but the iphone can detect a touch and then Safari can fire the touchstart event.  Then we can catch it in JavaScript and perform some action. So, yes, I'm talking about what Google does in their JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

There are touch-specific DOM Events. They've implemented a lot of JavaScript logic around them. Read the [Safari Web Content Guideline: Handling Events Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html) Also checkout out the [official spec for Touch Events](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webevents/raw-file/tip/touchevents.html)

A while back, I wrote a quick library to wrap some native-like gestures as HTML events [JSGestureRecognizer](https://github.com/paularmstrong/JSGestureRecognizer). I don't really recommend using that library in production, but reading the source should give you a pretty good idea about how google went about listening to native Touch Events and doing complex user interfaces with them.